# PDF generates on the backend but is blank in the browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, pdfkit

Hi I have a problem PDFkit generates PDF file in nodejs (with the hello world text) but in the browser I am given the blank page.

browser code

```
const getOrderPdf = async (): Promise<void> => {
      console.log(orderId);
      const response = await getOrderRaport();
      console.log(response);
      const file = window.URL.createObjectURL(
        new Blob([response], { type: "application/pdf" }),
      );
      window.open(file);
    };
```

server side

```
export const getOrderRaport = async (
  req: Request<{}, {}, {}>,
  res: Response,
  next: NextFunction,
) => {
  const pdfName = `order-raport-634320c8df6fad44f1dce4e8.pdf`;
  const pdfDoc = new PDFDocument();
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
  res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', `inline; filename=${pdfName}`);
  pdfDoc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream("./order-raport-634320c8df6fad44f1dce4e8.pdf"))
  pdfDoc.text("Hello world!")
  pdfDoc.pipe(res)
  pdfDoc.end();
};
```